# How do you set this rspec example on has and belongs to many association

Tags: ruby-on-rails, rspec

Having trouble framing this assertion in Rspec for my rails app.  A `User` has a habtm association to `Role`, I want to assert that, after my test a User should should be associated to a role with a title of "Superuser".  In the rails console.

```
user.roles.where(title: "Superuser").any?
=> true
```

How would that look in rspec what I'd like to say is 'user has a role titled "Superuser"'

thanks,

Answer (score 1, accepted):

How about something like this:

```
user.roles.where(title: "Superuser").should_not be_empty
```

Comment: ya, that worked exactly. So clear but for the life of me I couldn't piece it together

Answer (score 0):

I have been looking to setup a spec to test the `has_and_belongs_to_many` relationship between two models myself. And if anyone is looking to test the relationship this might be helpful to them:

```
it "should have and belong many to Categories" do
  assc = described_class.reflect_on_association(:categories)
  expect(assc.macro).to eq :has_and_belongs_to_many
end
```